# Overriding existing model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-models

I am trying to override an existing active record model but the new active record model doesn't have methods from the old active record model. Here is the code that I am trying to use

```
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base

   def method_modela_1
     logger.info "I am in method_modela_1"
   end

   def method_modelb_2
      logger.info " I am in method_modelb_2"
   end
end
```

Next I override the ModelA with ModelB

```
class ModelB < ModelA
   def foo
      logger.info "foo method from model B"
   end
end
```

So now I am trying to write a code that is trying to access find_or_create_by using the following code

```
some_variable = ModelB.find_or_create_by(:id => 1234)
```

but it says     `***** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method 'find_or_create_by' for ModelB:Module**`

What am I missing? For record I am using `'rails', '4.2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword is "NoMethodError Exception: undefined method 'find_or_create_by' for ModelB:**Module**".

You have a `module ModelB` somewhere and, due to load order and/or constant lookup rules, it shadows your model.

Comment: You were right. I guess I need to comprehend the error messages better!. Thanks